# Arduino proceed multiple times of the same command from web browser (using WiServer.h)

Tags: arduino

I'm now using the Arduino + WiFiShield to create a door locker which could control the door lock remotely by a portable device with its browser. But it seems my program got a bug and I have no idea why it's happening.

The following is my bug.

My Arduino proceed multiple times of the same command sent from web browser. 
  In other words, if I press the button appearing on the web browser, my Arduino will go to 
  execute the corresponding function I wrote in Arduino not only once but for multiple       times( usually 3 times, sometimes only twice...).

**Take my code for example, if I press the FORWARD button on web browser, my Arduino 
   will go to run the sub-function "closedoor();" for 3 times. The serial monitor is 
   giving back the log as below:**

```
Server connected
Processing request for /?V=C
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 329 bytes
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 329 bytes
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 174 bytes
Server connection closed
Server connected
Processing request for /favicon.ico
TX 19 bytes
Server connection closed
```

If I uncomment the "Serial.println(URL);", I will get the following log from serial monitor:

```
Server connected
Processing request for /?V=C
/?V=C
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 329 bytes
/?V=C
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 329 bytes
/?V=C
STOP : 
closingdoor : 
TX 174 bytes
Server connection closed
Server connected
Processing request for /favicon.ico
/favicon.ico
TX 19 bytes
Server connection closed
```

If someone knows something please give me a suggestion. I really need to figure it out.

The following is my code. Please have a look!!

```
#include <WiServer.h>

const int LMD18245_Brake = 4; // Pin 4 of Motoduino     
const int LMD18245_Direction = 5;  // Pin 5 of Motoduino   

// Wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------
unsigned char local_ip[]    = {192,168,1,5};   // IP address of WiShield
unsigned char gateway_ip[]  = {192,168,1,1};   // router or gateway IP address
unsigned char subnet_mask[] = {255,255,255,0}; // subnet mask for the local network
char ssid[]                 = {"Johnny"};   // max 32 bytes
unsigned char security_type = 2;               // 0 - open; 1 - WEP; 2 - WPA; 3 - WPA2

// WPA/WPA2 passphrase
const prog_char security_passphrase[] PROGMEM = {"xxxxxxxx"};   // max 64 characters

byte sampledata=50;
char link[]="http://motoduino.com/"; //link data

// WEP 128-bit keys
prog_uchar wep_keys[] PROGMEM = { 
    0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // Key 0
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // Key 1
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,   // Key 2
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00    // Key 3
};

// setup the wireless mode; infrastructure - connect to AP; adhoc - connect to another WiFi device
#define WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA 1
#define WIRELESS_MODE_ADHOC 2
unsigned char wireless_mode = WIRELESS_MODE_INFRA;
unsigned char ssid_len;
unsigned char security_passphrase_len;
// End of wireless configuration parameters ----------------------------------------

boolean mainpage()
{
          WiServer.print("<html><head></head>");
          WiServer.print("<body>");
          WiServer.print("<table border= 0>");
          WiServer.print("<tr>");
          WiServer.print("<th>  </th>");
          WiServer.print("<th>");
          WiServer.print("<form  method=get>");
          WiServer.print("<input type=hidden name=V value=C /><br />");
          WiServer.print("<input type=submit value=FORWARD>");
          WiServer.print("</form>");
          WiServer.print("</th><th> </th>");
          WiServer.print("</tr>");
          WiServer.print("<tr><th>");
          WiServer.print("<form  method=get >");
          WiServer.print("<input type=hidden name=V value=O /><br />");
          WiServer.print("<input type=submit value=LEFT>");
          WiServer.print("</form>");
          WiServer.print("</th><th>");
          WiServer.print("<form  method=get >");
          WiServer.print("<input type=hidden name=V value=S /><br />");
          WiServer.print("<input type=submit value=STOP>");
          WiServer.print("</form>");
          WiServer.print("</th><th> ");
          WiServer.print("<form  method=get >");
          WiServer.print("<input type=hidden name=V value=R /><br />");
          WiServer.print("<input type=submit value=RIGHT>");
          WiServer.print("</form>");
          WiServer.print("</th></tr> <tr> <th>  </th> <th> ");
          WiServer.print("<form  method=get >");
          WiServer.print("<input type=hidden name=V value=B /><br />");
          WiServer.print("<input type=submit value=BACKWARD>");
          WiServer.print("</form>");
          WiServer.print(" </th> <th> </th> </tr>");
          WiServer.print("</table>");
          WiServer.print("<br/>");
          WiServer.print("<font color=#888888 size=1>Project_Test</font><font size=3>");
          WiServer.print("<br /></font><font size=3> Johnny</font><br />");
          WiServer.print("</body>");
          WiServer.print("</html>");

          return true; 
}

boolean  controlpage(char* URL)
{
//    Serial.println(URL);
    if (strcmp(URL, "/") == 0)
    {
          mainpage();  
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         if(URL[1] == '?')
         {
           if((URL[2] == 'V') && (URL[3] == '='))
           {
              switch(URL[4])
              {

                 case 'C': 
                           closedoor(); 
                          break;
                 case 'O': 
                           opendoor(); 
                          break;
                 case 'S': 
                           stopmode(); 
                          break;   
                 default:
                 //Do nothing
                          break;            
              }
           mainpage();  
           return true;    
           }
          mainpage();  
          return true;          
         }      

    }
}

void opendoor()
{
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Brake, 0);
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Direction, 1);
  delay(200);
  stopmode();

  Serial.println("openingdoor : ");
}

void closedoor()
{
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Brake, 0);
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Direction, 0);
  delay(200);
  stopmode();

  Serial.println("closingdoor : ");
}

void stopmode()
{
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Brake, 1);
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Direction, 0);

  Serial.println("STOP : ");
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // set all color leds as output pins
  pinMode(LMD18245_Brake, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LMD18245_Direction, OUTPUT);

  WiServer.init(controlpage);
  digitalWrite( LMD18245_Brake, 1);
  // Enable Serial output and ask WiServer to generate log messages (optional)
  WiServer.enableVerboseMode(true);
}

void loop(){

  // Run WiServer
  WiServer.server_task();

  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you uncomment the first line of function controlpage(Serial.println(URL)). Is your output"urlname: closing door: STOP: " repeated three times, or is it something else. I think the output here should give us some ideas.

Comment: Hi @sraok ,
Thanks for your reply!
If I uncomment the "Serial.println(URL);" I will get a repeated 3 times feedback during in one connection. I have updated the log from
serial monitor after I uncomment the "Serial.println(URL);".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the small buffer on the atmega328 (or similar) that the wishield library was created for.

The atmega328 has a very limited RAM, so they are forced to use a small buffer.
If you "grep" for SIZE in the library, I believe that is the line that defines it:

uipopt.h:#define UIP_BUFSIZE     400

So once the headers for IP packet are in, it appears there is about 329 bytes left for the payload.

So what happens if your page contains more than that ?

The library just calls your page over and over, and remembers when it was last time, and the next time over, it transmits the next 329 bytes segment, until the last segments fits into 329 bytes and then it's done.

I don't see any other way of going at it, but it can have annoying side effects if you don't transmit the same thing every single time. You *have* to transmit the same thing every single time until it's done.

They seemed to have planned to implement a method to tell you that it's "in progress", but the code isn't there:

```
boolean Server::sendInProgress() {
        return false; // FIX ME
}
```

So, in a nutshell, it's normal, but make sure you transmit the same content every time, and that the size of what you transmit never changes for a given page.

Needless to say, this was designed to transmit static pages, not to run something too fancy with dynamic content created on the fly, although it can be done, to a certain extent, if you are careful.

By the way, I wouldn't try to change the #define'd size there, because then you will run out of stack space before you know it, and that can be pretty hard to debug.

If you really need to be called only once, then you have to shave some of what you are transmitting for that given URL until it comes in under 329 bytes (according to your logs). Then it should call you only once.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. At least I got figured out where is the problem. I think I will try to modify my code and make sure it will transmit the given URL under 329 bytes.